# Got AbstractMethodError when running Zeppelin Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, netty, mesos, apache-zeppelin

I installed Zeppelin 0.8 on one of my Mesos slave(our mesos cluster is a 3 masters + 5 slaves cluster. We use Apache Marathon to lunch my spark job normally.), and we got below exception when launching one of the spark job through Zeppelin. Looks like it is related with io.netty not matching.

I checked all my spark job fat jar, looks like they are using Netty 4.1.13 due to a dependency from an Elastic Search plugin.

After investigation I noticed one thing, as long as I add my Spark job fat jar to Zeppelin's Spark kernel, this error will happen even though I am running Zeppelin tutorial.

My Spark binaries are installed on all the Mesos slaves and version is 2.1.0.

If this is due to Netty issue, my jobs should not be able to run when I submit the job using Apache Marathon. However it only fails when running through Zeppelin.

Anybody can give me some hint? Thanks in advance!

```
INFO [2018-09-27 01:13:41,532] ({Thread-26} Logging.scala[logInfo]:54) - Mesos task 2 is now TASK_RUNNING
ERROR [2018-09-27 01:13:43,778] ({shuffle-server-3-4} TransportRequestHandler.java[operationComplete]:201) - Error sending result RpcResponse{requestId=4631687762231387177, body=NioManagedBuffer{buf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=47 cap=64]}} to /10.128.96.44:44904; closing connection
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.touch(ReferenceCountUtil.java:73)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:107)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:810)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:111)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:816)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:723)
at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.write(IdleStateHandler.java:302)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1089)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1136)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1078)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And below is my config in zeppelin-env.sh.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY="/usr/lib/libmesos.so"

export MASTER="mesos://zk://10.128.96.35:2181,10.128.96.37:2181,10.128.96.39:2181,10.128.96.41:2181,10.128.96.43:2181/mesos" # Get the master zk string for your environment from RCS.

export ZEPPELIN_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.executor.memory=4g -Dspark.cores.max=2"

export ZEPPELIN_MEM="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

export ZEPPELIN_INTP_MEM="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark"

export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--driver-memory 1G --executor-memory 4G"

export SPARK_APP_NAME="Zeppelin"
```

Comment: I guess there may be some other jars in your classpath, Could you try to use another clean version of spark ? It is not necessary to install it on all nodes, just on the zeppelin host.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a both netty 4.0.x and 4.1.x on the classpath. You should only have 4.1.x

Comment: Thanks @norman! I only have 4.1.X in my class path. Not sure if Spark/Zeppelin is using a different one. Is it possible to change the Netty to 4.0.X in Spark 2.1.0? (I doubt after googling). Will it work if I fully exclude Netty in my fat jar?

Answer (score 0):

Some codes like below in my build.sbt resolve the issue.

```
assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter { entry =>
        entry.data.getName == "netty-all-4.1.10.Final.jar" ||
        entry.data.getName == "netty-buffer-4.1.13.Final.jar" ||
        entry.data.getName == "netty-codec-4.1.13.Final.jar" ||
        entry.data.getName == "netty-codec-http-4.1.13.Final.jar" ||
        entry.data.getName == "netty-common-4.1.13.Final.jar" ||
        entry.data.getName == "netty-handler-4.1.13.Final.jar" ||
        entry.data.getName == "netty-resolver-4.1.13.Final.jar"  ||
        entry.data.getName == "netty-transport-4.1.13.Final.jar" }
}
```